# wait until finish loading a curl exec and then display

Tags: php, parsing, curl, load

Hi all and thanks in advance for reading, am having trouble with curl php i made a file.php
in fact the file it work fine my only issue is that when i pulling out the data it takes as minimum 20 secs and i want to speed up the process or make something to load the curl_exec and make sure that is fully loaded and the show it, because i have the problem that even some images in the table that is being loaded don't appear. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$values = parse_url($ref);

$pedazo = explode("/", $ref);

switch ($pedazo[4]) {
    case 'page-bajio.php':
        // Initialise a cURL object
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set url and other options

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.directoriomex.com.mx/basebaj.asp");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);

        // Get the page contents
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        echo "Fueron {$info['total_time']} segundos para la url {$info['url']}<br>" . 
             $info['content_type']. "<br>" . 
             $info['http_code'] . "<br>" .
             $info['header_size'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['request_size'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['filetime'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['ssl_verify_result'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['redirect_count'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['total_time'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['namelookup_time'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['connect_time'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['pretransfer_time'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['size_upload'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['size_download'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['speed_download'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['speed_upload'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['download_content_length'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['upload_content_length'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['starttransfer_time'] . "<br>" . 
             $info['redirect_time'] . "<br>";

        curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;
        break;

    default:
        header("location:../initializr");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Try increasing php file's execution time. Set set_time_limit(0); as first line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to prevent bits of your page to show before the page is "fully loaded" by the server.

Try to set implicit flush to off at the beginning of your script ([see docs here](http://pt1.php.net/ob_implicit_flush))

```
ob_implicit_flush(false);
```

you can also set an output buffer and manually flush it afterwards, like this:

```
ob_start();
//your script goes here
ob_end_flush();
```

Documentation of output buffering can be found **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)**

Comment: well i did try the both options but the result were the same, i didn't see the image instead of letters of the url and it still took a lot of time to load.

Comment: now am wondering why if i go direct to the url http://www.directoriomex.com.mx/basebaj.asp, almost all items got a link and in my $output all links doesn't work. Could i fix this with any curl option? or is there any workaround. :/